# Ionic asset file location for web and devices with angular http

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to read file from asset. My code is:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";

.
.
  assetURL: string = "../assets/";
  androidAssetURL: string = "'../www/assets/";

.
.

public readAssetFile(fileName: string) {
    var url = this.assetURL + fileName;

    if (this.platform.is("cordova") && this.platform.is("android")) {
      url = this.androidAssetURL + fileName;
    }

    this.log("reading data file location:" + url);
    return this.http
      .get(url, { responseType: "text" })
      .first()
      .toPromise();
  }
```

the location works for web

> reading data file location:../assets/data/about

but on device I get the location

> reading data file location:'../www/assets/data/about

but the real content isn't read instead, get the HTML below as content

```
data file:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <script data-ionic="inject">
    (function(w){var i=w.Ionic=w.Ionic||{};i.version='3.9.2';i.angular='5.2.11';i.staticDir='build/';})(window);
  </script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <met
.
.
.
```

Comment: have a same question, did you found solution for that

Comment: I just added an extension to the files. Somehow that fixed the issue. Now same url works on device and browser. /assets/data/about.txt

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extension fixed the issue and it works on both browser and device.

where file param is "about.txt" and not "about"

```
  //strings
  assetURL: string = "/assets/data/";

 //to read
  getData(file: string) {
    this.readAssetData(file).subscribe(
      it => {
        this.core.log("data file:" + it);
          this.pageText = it;
      },
      err => {
        this.core.log("error read file:" + JSON.stringify(err));
      }
    );
  }

  public readAssetData(fileName: string) {
    var url = this.assetURL + fileName;

    this.log("reading data file location:" + url);
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: "text" });
  }
```